# react взаимодействие с сервером

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

Не могу понять как взаимодействовать с сервером.

http://localhost/ - отбражаю вёрстку index.html

http://localhost/men - на этот запрос я получаю JSON

Но если я перехожу сразу по ссылке http://localhost/men, то index.html не отдаётся и вместо вёрстки у меня данные.

Я не могу понять как мне одновременно получать и верстку и данные

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо добавить на страницу `index.html` `javascript`, который обращается за данными к серверу и обработать их, например при помощи `fetch`:

```
fetch('http://localhost/men')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
     console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: но  я так и делаю

Comment: @DmitryFilippov тогда я не пойму, что  у Вас не получается

Comment: сервер отдает при запросе http://localhost/men json. а не index.html. Поэтому если обновить страницу с этим url http://localhost/men, то на экране будет json

Comment: @DmitryFilippov а и не надо переходить по этому url, к нему нужно обращаться только из скрипта

Comment: а если нужно? не всегда же заходят на сайт с главной страницы

Comment: @DmitryFilippov а зачем это нужно-то? ну переходят и переходят, пусть увидят сырые данные

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90809/discussion-between-dmitry-filippov-and-stranger-in-the-q).